# Random numbers and number filters in excel

Tags: excel

I have been trying to learn to use excel "number filters".  I generated 100 integers between 1 and 100 at random using ceiling(100*rand(), 1).  I then labeled this column 'Scores' and used a number filter where 50 < Scores < 100.  However, it is returning values outside this range, like 23, 9, 13, etc..  It seems to work fine when I actually type in numbers, so I'm assuming the seeding may be causing an issue (?).  Is there a way to use the number filter on random number sets?

Comment: Rand is volatile and the very act of filtering causes it to recalculate and change.  Try copying and pasting the values then filtering.

Comment: Also, consider using RANDBETWEEN()

Comment: or setting the sheet to manually calculate instead of automatically updating every time a cell is changed.

Answer (score 1):

As Scott mentioned Rand function is volatile and one way to stop it from updating is to `Copy> Paste Special> Values`

The another way to accomplish this is by creating circular reference. I am assuming your "Scores" column is Column "A". In another cell say `B2` enter "change". Now in the cell `A2` enter your formula as `=IF($B$2="change",CEILING(100*RAND(),1),A2)`.

If you do not want random numbers to change their values, just change the value in cell `B2` to anything other then "change"